# Ascending order Sorted array is getting printed in descending order?

Tags: java, sorting, matrix

```
   public void sortcolumn(double[] arraytosort) {
    a = new int[5];
    for (int i = 1; i < arraytosort.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < arraytosort.length; j++) {
            if ((arraytosort[i]) > (arraytosort[j])) {
                tempVar = arraytosort[j];
                arraytosort[j] = arraytosort[i];
                arraytosort[i] = tempVar;
                a[i] = j;
              }
      }
 System.out.println( a[i]);
    }
}


public void decisionvalue(double[][] arraydc){
    arrtemp = new double[arraydc.length];
    for(int i =0; i<arraydc[0].length;i++){
        System.out.println("The column matrix is");
        for(int j =1; j<arraydc.length;j++){
            arrtemp[j] =  arraydc[j][i];
        System.out.println(arrtemp[j]);
      }
        sortcolumn(arrtemp);
         System.out.println("The sorted column matrix is" +i);
        for(int k =1; k<arraydc.length; k++)
     System.out.println(arrtemp[k]);  
          }
  }
```

By the code above I am sorting the columns of an array and then printing them. But I don't understand why the ascending order sorted elements are printed in descending order. Someone please check it. Thanks!!

Following is the output:
This is the input matrix arraydc

0.0      0.0         0.0
25.0        10.0        24.0
25.0        5.0     23.0
25.0        23.0        6.0
25.0        89.0        8.0

---

The column matrix is
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0

---

0
0
0
0

---

The sorted column matrix is0
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0

---

The column matrix is
10.0
5.0
23.0
89.0

---

2
1
2
3

---

The sorted column matrix is1
89.0
23.0
10.0
5.0

---

The column matrix is
24.0
23.0
6.0
8.0

---

3
1
2
3

---

The sorted column matrix is2
24.0
23.0
8.0
6.0

---

Comment: what are you calling these functions with?

Comment: MattR i am calling these functions with a matrix I have shown in the output. Please see that. (arraydc matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
for (int j = i; j < arraytosort.length; j++) {
```

start from `i` in second loop

Comment: Waaao!! Thanks a lot!! it was such a silly mistake of mine.. Thanks again.. :)